# Return field as array from any map layer in QGIS expressions

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

In QGIS 3.8 It's obvious in the expression builder how to reference a layer or how to get a feature from a layer but not how to return a whole field from a layer.

[image: QGIS expression window]

What expression will return a field of a map layer as an array?

Comment: I'm having my first go at batch execution with my own processing model. The variable I'd like to iterate over is a numerical. I'd like to use the values from a field of an unrelated layer.

Comment: The answer could just be: "array_agg". Something like `aggregate('layer','array_agg',"field")` shoould work.

Comment: Thanks that was a big help. aggregate('Sandhills_cross_sections_aa303cb2_8f95_493d_8629_d8b19ee045d5', 'array_agg', "spill.elevation") worked to give me what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we want to perform operations on all (or a part of) the records of a particular field in a table, we generally use some aggregate function.

At some point, several aggregate functions were included in the QGIS Expression String Builder. Which are very useful to have available from there, since many components of the information system can now be defined through an expression.

The function that returns the values analyzed as an array is `array_agg()`. These values can even be the output of expressions and filters that operate on the records of the fields in a table.

On the other hand, the `aggregate()` function allows us to access the aggregate operations from any loaded layer.

In conclusion, the problem of returning all the records of a field from any loaded layer, in matrix form, can be solved through the function:

`aggregate( 'layer', 'array_aggr', "field")`